# Display multiple search results in R leaflet

Tags: r-leaflet

I have built a leaflet with circlemarkers and labels. I addes a search feature using addSearchFeatures. I have 100+ locations and each location is associated with a person's name. One person can be associated with more than one location. I would now like to search for a person's name and then have the leaflet display all their locations. So far the search find's a name but "chooses" one location of several possible. How can I have the leaflet display all locations associated with one name and not show any other location?

below is what I have coded so far:

```
library(leaflet.extras)

test_data \<- read.csv("\~/leaflet_search_test_example.csv")

map \<- leaflet() %\>%



addTiles(group = "OSM") %\>%
addProviderTiles("OpenTopoMap", group = "Topo Map") %\>%
addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "ESRI WorldImage") %\>%
addProviderTiles("Esri.OceanBasemap", group = "ESRI Ocean") %\>%


addCircleMarkers(data = test_data, test_data$Lon, test_data$Lat,
stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1,
label = test_data$Underwriter,
clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %\>%



addMarkers(
data = test_data, test_data$Lon, test_data$Lat, label = test_data$Underwriter,
group = 'Names', # this is the group to use in addSearchFeatures()
\# make custom icon that is so small you can't see it:
icon = makeIcon(
iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
iconWidth = 1, iconHeight = 1
)
) %\>%


addResetMapButton() %\>%


addSearchFeatures(
targetGroups = 'Names', 
options = searchFeaturesOptions(
zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE
)
) %\>%

addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("ESRI WorldImage (default)", "ESRI Ocean", "OSM", "Topo Map"),
options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))

map
```

I expect that if I search by Name, that the leaflet shows me all the locations belonging to that specific name.
Thank you for any tip you might have.